# How to display tool names?

Tags: 3d-view

Hello I'm watching a tutorial and the person has the names of their tools in sculpting mode which is very useful for quick selecting since I'm new to sculpting but I don't have them.
Left side is my screen, right screen is his. I'm on 2.83, he's on 2.80. I've already looked in the preferences and view settings unless there's something I missed. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just enlarge the toolbar from its right:

[image]

As you can see rapidly in the gif above, there are three display modes:

- Icons in one column (scrollable)
- Compact two columns (see picture below)
- Icons and names in one column (scrollable also)

[image]